# What is the best way to make Add, Edit, Delete and List actions in one View

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I'm converting a huge web application from `ASP.Net 3.5` to `ASP.Net MVC3` and `C# 4.0` using `VS2010`, about **90%** of site pages has Add, Edit, Delete, And List actions. If I create one view for each action that means each page will converting to 4 view (4 physical files) but I don't like that but I can do it if I have to. :(

My question is Is there an **elegant** way to converting one `ASP.Net` page to one `View` contains all required action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one view to do this. Each user action will route to a respective controller action via a form post. Inside the controller action the model will be updated and then the controller action will redirect to the view.

Personally, I wouldn't have an issue converting one page to four views if it is meaningful to do so in terms of maintenance. If they are similar in structure, a lot of the repetition can be abstracted out into Layouts, Partials and other views.

Comment: could you please give me more explanation for your idea?